# When and how should I perform floating point conversion in my simd routine?

Tags: assembly, x86, sse, simd, webassembly

I'm calculating a two-way (horizontal and vertical) prefix sum (scan) over 2 images yielding sums of the pixels, sums of the squares, and the cross product of the two images.  All of the calculations are done in 32bit integers before I get to the final pass which needs to convert 32bit integers to doubles to calculate the mean, variances, and covariance of both images in a windowing function.

First -- is this the optimal way to do this?  I could build the entire prefix sum array in doubles and there would be no conversion step.

Second -- if this is the right way, do I get many benefits from using the packed double simd operations?  I can only safely assume I'll get 2 units out at a time.

Third -- Should I pack the data units together or leave it in the planar format it's currently in?  [A Planar format is one in which the pixels are broken out by 'component'.  If you were getting 32bit RGBA inputs which is  8bit R, 8 bit G, 8 bit B, and  8 bit A, the packed format would be RGBARGBA, whereas the planar format would RRRRRRRRRRRRR....GGGGGGGGGGGG....BBBBB.....AAAAA... and so on.]

The following are the three functions that I have done so far related to this topic.  The first 2 are scalar versions so it's easier to read and understand what's going on.  The third is the current SIMD implementation of function 1.  The fourth function ( which is missing and not yet complete ) is the topic of this question and likely the  SIMD implementation of the second.

```
std::unique_ptr<uint32_t[],boost::alignment::aligned_delete> computeSumMatrixForwardScalar2PassAll(uint8_t const* pImgData1, uint8_t const* pImgData2,
                                                                                                unsigned width, unsigned height)
{
  using namespace simdpp;
  std::unique_ptr<uint32_t[], boost::alignment::aligned_delete> sumArray((uint32_t*)boost::alignment::aligned_alloc(64, 5*width*height*sizeof(uint32_t)));
  auto pSumArray = sumArray.get();
  BOOST_ALIGN_ASSUME_ALIGNED(pImgData1, 64);
  BOOST_ALIGN_ASSUME_ALIGNED(pImgData2, 64);
  BOOST_ALIGN_ASSUME_ALIGNED(pSumArray, 64);
//#pramga omp parallel for private(h) shared(pImgData, pSumArray, w )

#pragma omp for simd
  for (unsigned h = 0; h < height; ++h)
  {
    uint32_t lastValX = 0;
    uint32_t lastValY = 0;
    uint32_t lastValXX = 0;
    uint32_t lastValYY = 0;
    uint32_t lastValXY = 0;
    for (unsigned w = 0; w < width; ++w)
    {
      uint32_t imgValX      = pImgData1[h * width + w];
      uint32_t newValX      = lastValX + imgValX;
      uint32_t newValXX = lastValXX + imgValX*imgValX;
      uint32_t imgValY = pImgData2[h*width + w];
      uint32_t newValY = lastValY + imgValY;
      uint32_t newValYY = lastValYY + imgValY*imgValY;
      uint32_t newValXY = lastValXY + imgValX*imgValY;
      pSumArray[h*width + w]= newValX;
      pSumArray[width*height+h*width + w] = newValY;
      pSumArray[2*width*height+ h*width + w] = newValXX;

      pSumArray[3*width*height+h*width + w] = newValYY;
      pSumArray[4*width*height+h*width + w] = newValXY;
      lastValX              = newValX;
      lastValXX = newValXX;
      lastValY = newValY;
      lastValYY = newValYY;
      lastValXY = newValXY;
    }
  }
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    for (unsigned h = 0; h+1 < height; ++h)
    {
      for (unsigned w = 0; w < width; ++w) {
        uint32_t above = pSumArray[i*width*height + h * width + w];
        uint32_t current = pSumArray[i*width*height+ (h+1) *width +w];
        pSumArray[i*width*height + (h+1) * width +w]= above+current;
      }
    }
  }

  return sumArray;
}
```

Second: the SSIM Conversion -- note different language -- because I haven't finished the C++ implementation of it yet. Note, it calls weberSumMatrix in there which is identical to the above function.

```
export function weberSsim(
  pixels1: ImageMatrix,
  pixels2: ImageMatrix,
  options: Options
): MSSIMMatrix {
  // console.time("weber ssim");
  const { bitDepth, k1, k2, windowSize} = options
  const L = (1 << bitDepth) - 1
  const c1 = k1 * L * (k1 * L)
  const c2 = k2 * L * (k2 * L)
  const windowSquared = windowSize * windowSize
  const pixels1Data = pixels1.data;
  const pixels2Data = pixels2.data;
  const width = pixels1.width;
  const height = pixels1.height;
  // Produces exactly the same output as the C++ prefix sum above.
  const sumMatrix = weberSumMatrix(pixels1Data, pixels2Data, width, height);
  const windowHeight = height-windowSize;
  const windowWidth = width-windowSize;
  const imageSize = width*height;
  const ssims = new Array(windowHeight*windowWidth);


  // lets handle w = 0 h = 0 first and initialize mssim

  let cumulativeSsim;
  const reciprocalWindowSquared =  1 / windowSquared;
  {
    const windowOffset = windowSize - 1;
    let bottomOffset = windowOffset*width;
    {
      const meanx = (sumMatrix[bottomOffset+ windowOffset]) * reciprocalWindowSquared;
      const meany = (
        sumMatrix[imageSize + bottomOffset+ windowOffset]) * reciprocalWindowSquared;
      const varx = (
        sumMatrix[2*imageSize + bottomOffset+ windowOffset]) * reciprocalWindowSquared - meanx*meanx ;
      const vary = (
        sumMatrix[3*imageSize + bottomOffset+ windowOffset])  * reciprocalWindowSquared - meany*meany;
      const cov = (
        sumMatrix[4*imageSize + bottomOffset+ windowOffset])  * reciprocalWindowSquared - meanx*meany;
      const na = 2 * meanx * meany + c1
      const nb = 2 * cov + c2
      const da = meanx * meanx + meany * meany + c1
      const db = varx + vary + c2
      const ssim = (na * nb) / (da * db)
      ssims[0] = ssim
      // mssim = ssim
      cumulativeSsim = ssim;
    }



    // next handle all of the h = 0, w > 0 cases first
    for (let w = 1; w <  windowWidth; ++w) {
      // in h =0 cases, there is no top left or top right
      let leftOffset = w - 1;
      const rightx = sumMatrix[bottomOffset+leftOffset];
      const leftx = sumMatrix[bottomOffset+(windowOffset+w)];
      const meanx = (leftx-rightx)* reciprocalWindowSquared;
      const righty= sumMatrix[imageSize + bottomOffset+ leftOffset];
      const lefty = sumMatrix[imageSize + bottomOffset+ (windowOffset+w)];
      const meany = (lefty-righty) * reciprocalWindowSquared;
      const rightxx = sumMatrix[2*imageSize + bottomOffset+leftOffset];
      const leftxx = sumMatrix[2*imageSize + bottomOffset+ (windowOffset+w)];
      const varx = (leftxx-rightxx) * reciprocalWindowSquared - meanx*meanx ;
      const rightyy = sumMatrix[3*imageSize + bottomOffset+leftOffset];
      const leftyy = sumMatrix[3*imageSize + bottomOffset+ (windowOffset+w)]
      const vary = (leftyy - rightyy)  * reciprocalWindowSquared - meany*meany;
      const rightxy = sumMatrix[4*imageSize + bottomOffset+leftOffset];
      const leftxy = sumMatrix[4*imageSize + bottomOffset+ (windowOffset+w)];
      const cov = (leftxy-rightxy)  * reciprocalWindowSquared - meanx*meany;
      const na = 2 * meanx * meany + c1
      const nb = 2 * cov + c2
      const da = meanx * meanx + meany * meany + c1
      const db = varx + vary + c2
      const ssim = (na * nb) / (da *db)
      ssims[w] = ssim
      // mssim = mssim + (ssim - mssim) / (i + 1)
      cumulativeSsim += ssim;
    }
  }

  const windowOffset = windowSize - 1;
  // There will be lots of branch misses if we don't split the w==0 and h==0 cases
  for (let h = 1; h < windowHeight; ++h) {
    // now the w=0 on each line
    let bottomOffset = (h+windowSize-1)*width;
    let topOffset = (h-1)*width;
    {
      // since there is no left side we can skip two operations
      const topx = sumMatrix[topOffset+ windowOffset];
      const bottomx = sumMatrix[bottomOffset+ windowOffset];
      const meanx = (bottomx - topx) * reciprocalWindowSquared;
      const topy = sumMatrix[imageSize + topOffset+ windowOffset];
      const bottomy = sumMatrix[imageSize + bottomOffset+ windowOffset];
      const meany = (bottomy - topy) * reciprocalWindowSquared;
      const topxx = sumMatrix[2*imageSize + topOffset+ windowOffset];
      const bottomxx = sumMatrix[2*imageSize + bottomOffset+ windowOffset];
      const varx = (bottomxx-topxx)  * reciprocalWindowSquared - meanx*meanx ;
      const topyy = sumMatrix[3*imageSize + topOffset+ windowOffset];
      const bottomyy = sumMatrix[3*imageSize + bottomOffset+ windowOffset];
      const vary = (bottomyy-topyy)  * reciprocalWindowSquared - meany*meany;
      const topxy = sumMatrix[4*imageSize + topOffset+ windowOffset];
      const bottomxy = sumMatrix[4*imageSize + bottomOffset+ windowOffset];
      const cov = (bottomxy-topxy)  * reciprocalWindowSquared - meanx*meany;
      const na = 2 * meanx * meany + c1
      const nb = 2 * cov + c2
      const da = meanx * meanx + meany * meany + c1
      const db = varx + vary + c2
      const ssim = (na * nb) / (da *db)
      ssims[h*windowWidth] = ssim
      // mssim = mssim + (ssim - mssim) / (i + 1)
      cumulativeSsim += ssim;
    }


    for (let w = 1; w < windowWidth; ++w) {
      // add top left sub top right sub bottom left add bottom right
      const rightOffset = w + windowSize - 1;
      const leftOffset = w - 1;
      const meanx = (sumMatrix[topOffset + leftOffset]
        - sumMatrix[topOffset+ rightOffset]
        - sumMatrix[bottomOffset+leftOffset]
        + sumMatrix[bottomOffset+ rightOffset]) * reciprocalWindowSquared;
      const meany = (sumMatrix[imageSize+ topOffset + leftOffset]
        - sumMatrix[imageSize + topOffset+ rightOffset]
        - sumMatrix[imageSize + bottomOffset+leftOffset]
        + sumMatrix[imageSize + bottomOffset+ rightOffset]) * reciprocalWindowSquared;
      const varx = (sumMatrix[2*imageSize+ topOffset + leftOffset]
        - sumMatrix[2*imageSize + topOffset+ rightOffset]
        - sumMatrix[2*imageSize + bottomOffset+leftOffset]
        + sumMatrix[2*imageSize + bottomOffset+ rightOffset]) * reciprocalWindowSquared - meanx*meanx ;
      const vary = (sumMatrix[3*imageSize+ topOffset + leftOffset]
        - sumMatrix[3*imageSize + topOffset+ rightOffset]
        - sumMatrix[3*imageSize + bottomOffset+leftOffset]
        + sumMatrix[3*imageSize + bottomOffset+ rightOffset])  * reciprocalWindowSquared - meany*meany;
      const cov = (sumMatrix[4*imageSize+ topOffset + leftOffset]
        - sumMatrix[4*imageSize + topOffset+ rightOffset]
        - sumMatrix[4*imageSize + bottomOffset+leftOffset]
        + sumMatrix[4*imageSize + bottomOffset+ rightOffset])  * reciprocalWindowSquared - meanx*meany;
      const na = 2 * meanx * meany + c1
      const nb = 2 * cov + c2
      const da = meanx * meanx + meany * meany + c1
      const db = varx + vary + c2
      const ssim = (na * nb) / (da * db)
      ssims[h*windowWidth+w] = ssim
      cumulativeSsim += ssim;
      // mssim = mssim + (ssim - mssim) / (i + 1)
    }
  }
  const mssim = cumulativeSsim / (windowHeight*windowWidth);


  return { data: ssims, width, height, mssim }
}
```

Third: Current SIMD prefix sum.

```
std::unique_ptr<uint32_t[],boost::alignment::aligned_delete> computeSumMatrixForwardSimd2PassAll(uint8_t const* pImgData1, uint8_t const* pImgData2,
                                                                                              unsigned width, unsigned height)
{
  using namespace simdpp;
  std::unique_ptr<uint32_t[], boost::alignment::aligned_delete> sumArray((uint32_t*)boost::alignment::aligned_alloc(64, 5*width*height*sizeof(uint32_t)));
  auto pSumArray = sumArray.get();
  BOOST_ALIGN_ASSUME_ALIGNED(pImgData1, 64);
  BOOST_ALIGN_ASSUME_ALIGNED(pImgData2, 64);
  BOOST_ALIGN_ASSUME_ALIGNED(pSumArray, 64);
//#pramga omp parallel for private(h) shared(pImgData, pSumArray, w )


  uint32x4 zero = make_zero();
  for (unsigned h = 0; h < height; ++h)
  {
    uint32x4 lastValSplatX = zero;
    uint32x4 lastValSplatY = zero;
    uint32x4 lastValSplatXX = zero;
    uint32x4 lastValSplatYY = zero;
    uint32x4 lastValSplatXY = zero;
    for (unsigned w = 0; w < width; w += 16)
    {
      // starting left value
      // previous line values..
      prefetch_read(pImgData1+(w+1)*64);
      prefetch_read(pImgData2+(w+1)*64);
      uint32v4 imgDataX = to_uint32(uint8x16(load(pImgData1 + h * width + w)));
      uint32v4 imgDataY = to_uint32(uint8x16(load(pImgData2 + h * width + w)));
      static_assert(uint32v4::vec_length == 4);
      static_assert(sizeof(uint32v4::base_vector_type::native_type) == 16);
      for (unsigned i = 0 ; i < uint32v4::vec_length; ++i) {
        // a_0 a_1 a_2 a_3
        uint32v4::base_vector_type   x = imgDataX.vec(i);
        uint32v4::base_vector_type  y = imgDataY.vec(i);
        uint32v4::base_vector_type xx = mul_lo(x,x);
        uint32v4::base_vector_type yy = mul_lo(y, y);
        uint32v4::base_vector_type xy = mul_lo(x, y);
        // a_0 a_0+a_1 a_1+a_2 a_2+a_3
        x = add(x, move4_r<1>(x));
        x = add(x, move4_r<2>(x));
        x = add(x, lastValSplatX);
        lastValSplatX = permute4<3,3,3,3>(x);
        store(pSumArray+h*width+w+i*4, x);
        y = add(y, move4_r<1>(y));
        y = add(y, move4_r<2>(y));
        y = add(y, lastValSplatY);
        lastValSplatY = permute4<3,3,3,3>(y);
        store(width*height+pSumArray+h*width+w+i*4, y);
        xx = add(xx, move4_r<1>(xx));
        xx = add(xx, move4_r<2>(xx));
        xx = add(xx, lastValSplatXX);
        lastValSplatXX = permute4<3,3,3,3>(xx);
        store(2*width*height+pSumArray+h*width+w+i*4, xx);
        yy = add(yy, move4_r<1>(yy));
        yy = add(yy, move4_r<2>(yy));
        yy = add(yy, lastValSplatYY);
        lastValSplatYY = permute4<3,3,3,3>(yy);
        store(3*width*height+pSumArray+h*width+w+i*4, yy);
        xy = add(xy, move4_r<1>(xy));
        xy = add(xy, move4_r<2>(xy));
        xy = add(xy, lastValSplatXY);
        lastValSplatXY = permute4<3,3,3,3>(xy);
        store(4*width*height+pSumArray+h*width+w+i*4, xy);
      }
    }
  }
  // 16 bit 8s for grins...
  // a_0 a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4 a_5 a_6 a_7
  // a_0 a_0+a_1 a_1+a_2 a_2+a_3 a_3+a_4 a_4+a_5 a_5+a_6 a_6+a_7 (>>1)
  // d    d        -a_0  -a_0+a_1 -a_0+a_1+a_2 -a_0+a_1+a_2+a_3 -a_0+a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4 - -a_0+a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5
  // d    d        shuffle shuffle shuffle+add    shuffle+add     shuffle+add+shuffle+add  shuffle+add+shuffle+add


  // a_0 a_1 a_2 a_3     a_4         a_5           a_6                    a_7
  //         a_0 a_1     a_2         a_3           a_4                    a_5
  //         a_1 a_2+a_0 a_3+a_1-a_0 a_4+a_2-a1-a0 a_5+a_3-a_2-a_0        a_6+a_4...
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    for (unsigned h = 0; h+1 < height; ++h)
    {
      for (unsigned w = 0; w < width; w += 16) {
        uint32v4 above = load(i*width*height +pSumArray + h * width + w);
        uint32v4 current = load(i*width*height+pSumArray +(h+1) * width +w);
        store(i*width*height+pSumArray +(h+1) * width +w, add(above,current));
      }
    }
  }

  return sumArray;
}
```

Comment: You're asking three separate questions at once.  Questions 1 and 2 are related, question 3 is something entirely different and is better suited for a separate question.  If you do post it, make sure to explain exactly what the “planar format” you have is exactly.  As is, it's hard to tell what you are asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First -- is this the optimal way to do this? I could build the entire prefix sum array in doubles and there would be no conversion step.

Generally, integer computations are considerably faster than floating point ones with the same number of elements per vector. For example, paddd has latency 1 and reciprocal throughput 0.33 cycles and addps - 4 and 0.5, respectively, on Skylake. With integer computations, if you have multiplications, you will sometimes have overhead due to having to convert between different element sizes or combining upper and lower halves of the product. But often that still ends up faster than FP, and you can also reduce it if you are able to incorporate pmaddwd or pmaddubsw instructions, which are INT versions of FMA, or you can discard lower or uppper half of the product.

Speaking of FMA, FP since AVX2 has advantage of having FMA instructions, which allow to have one addition per multiplication for free. Whether that would be beneficial in your case depends on your algorithm and input data, but if you have integer input I would still prefer INT computations on it as much as possible.

One additional advantage of INT computations over FP is that you can do computations on smaller elements, meaning that you can process more data per instruction. Of course, this is only possible when your input and algorithm permits that, but specifically in image processing this is often the case.

One final note on this part is that you should consider the amount of data you need to process on each stage of your algorithm. INT to FP conversion is not free, so the less data you need to convert the better. If the amount of your intermediate data is less than input then postponing the conversion will be beneficial.

> Second -- if this is the right way, do I get many benefits from using the packed double simd operations? I can only safely assume I'll get 2 units out at a time.

Well, 2 doubles per instruction is better than one, so in my book it is worth it. You are also able to perform more elaborate operations on vectors, like FMA, masking, blending, min/max, than on scalars (although the compiler may generate some instructions for you even on the scalar code). If you runtime detect AVX you can opportunistically double the throughput.

Also, you should consider if 32-bit float precision is enough in your case. You might not need double precision result, and by using some FP techniques you could reduce the error you accumulate with 32-bit FP math and still have better performance than with 64-bit calculations.

> Third -- Should I pack the data units together or leave it in the planar format it's currently in?

In general, you should prefer planar input data. SIMD in general and SSE/AVX in particular is better suited for vertical operations (i.e. when the operation is performed between corresponding elements of different vectors) rather than horizontal (when the operation is performed between elements of the same vector). With packed input you will likely have to perform unpacking and shuffling of the input data, which will add overhead. Modern CPUs are able to track more than one reading or writing streams from/to memory, so the hardware prefetcher should be able to handle linear memory accesses at different planes of data.

Comment: With respect to your comment about delaying the conversion when the intermediate data quantity is less, is well taken.  In my case, and if you look closely, you'll see that I have the opposite.  The intermediate data is 5x the quantity of the origin data.  Since I need to convert them all to uint32, the 5x holds through until the conversion to double exists.  In my case, I've determined that I can use floats up to the point of a 16x16 window size.  After that it appears double is the only option.  However, float isn't an option for the prefix sum table.

Comment: @DanWeber If your intermediate data is larger than input then you won't benefit from reducing the amount of conversion operations, but you may still win from the fact that some portion of your input processing is INT, which is faster than FP. It depends on how much you can do in INT.

Comment: Regarding the need to convert to uint32_t, note that during the accumulation stage you're adding 8-bit integers. The sum always fits in 16 bits, meaning that you can accumulate twice as many elements per instruction. And the "lastValXX + imgValX*imgValX" expression maps to pmaddwd instruction. Maybe even to pmaddubsw, if you can manage one of the vectors to have signed 8-bit elements.

Comment: One way to make use of pmaddubsw is to add a separate shift+addition for cases when one of the inputs is 128 or greater. Note that x * (128 + y) = x * 128 + x * y = (x << 7) + (x * y), where 0 <= y <= 127 and 0 <= x <= 255.

Answer (score 1):

To part 3 -- at the very least, the Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual specifies the planar format as being more ideal in general.  So I can cross that one-off.  Looks like I can do floating-point values instead of doubles for windows up to 16x16 (255*256**2) since that's representable before overflowing.  From that perspective, I get the benefit of the 4 floats per vector instead of 2 doubles.  That's helpful.  It seems then that I can get a rolling sum for my mean calculation off of the four floats and compute it at the end.  So if I constrain the function based off of the maximum window size, I can determine when to use float and when to use double.  The implementation isn't too different.

I guess I won't know the real performance of this until I try it and see.

Answer (score 0):

About part 1, depending on count of integers and their ranges, you might be good with 64-bit integers instead of doubles. Slightly faster in general especially latencies, also more precise. Here’s a few pieces in SSE2.

```
// Return acc64 += a32. The a32 is viewed as uint32_t lanes, the accumulator is uint64_t
inline __m128i integerAdd( __m128i a32, __m128i acc64 )
{
    const __m128i low = _mm_and_si128( a32, _mm_set1_epi64x( UINT_MAX ) );
    acc64 = _mm_add_epi64( acc64, low );
    const __m128i high = _mm_srli_epi64( a32, 32 );
    acc64 = _mm_add_epi64( acc64, high );
    return acc64;
}

// Compute a32 * b32, add to the accumulator. The two inputs are viewed as uint32_t lanes, the accumulator is uint64_t
inline __m128i integerFma( __m128i a32, __m128i b32, __m128i acc64 )
{
    const __m128i low = _mm_mul_epu32( a32, b32 );
    a32 = _mm_srli_si128( a32, 4 );
    b32 = _mm_srli_si128( b32, 4 );
    const __m128i high = _mm_mul_epu32( a32, b32 );
    acc64 = _mm_add_epi64( acc64, low );
    acc64 = _mm_add_epi64( acc64, high );
    return acc64;
}

// Add both 64-bit lanes of the accumulator, convert to double
inline double accumulatedValue( __m128i acc64 )
{
    acc64 = _mm_add_epi64( acc64, _mm_unpackhi_epi64( acc64, acc64 ) );
    const uint64_t v = (uint64_t)_mm_cvtsi128_si64( acc64 );
    return (double)v;
}
```

Update: Mean value is `sum(x) / count`. You don’t need fractions to compute sum of integers, you just need 64-bit integers to avoid overflow if you have lots of values. You only need non-integer number for one final instruction.

For the variance you need `sum((x-mean)^2)`. This can be re-written as `sum(x^2) + mean * ( mean - 2 * sum(x) )`. It’s now obvious you only need a single pass over the input data, computing sum of squares and sum of values. If you have too many inputs and they’re too large, computing sum of squares can overflow 64-bit integers. But for many practical applications it’s fine, e.g. if your inputs are within [0 .. 65535] range, 64-bit integers only overflow after 4 billion of samples, you probably don’t have that many.

Comment: I don't think this is helpful because I have no issues with uint32_t (even with overflow or rollover).  If I have to convert to a floating point type number to perform the final calculation, using 64bit integers doesn't do anything for me, unless you're proposing a way to do a fractional number calculation more efficiently.

Comment: How is mean guaranteed to be a whole number or integer without losing precision? I'm not concerned about overflow because the way the roundoff arithmetic works, it can handle an extra 65535 values which is larger than any reasonable window size.

Comment: @DanWeber The mean is not integer. However, sum of elements, and sum of their squares, are both guaranteed to be integers.
Once you’ve processed your complete input dataset, only then you need double math. Call `accumulatedValue()` on both accumulators, and do your double math. The performance no longer matters because these are just 2 numbers, even if you had a billion of elements on input.

Comment: Do you understand I'm working with images and that it's a two way prefix-sum?